# Graph Layout: Fixed node locations

Tags: graphs

I'm aware of a large amount of literature on the problem of graph layout. Usually this involves taking a list of nodes and edges, and choosing locations and paths for both respectively. Are there any algorithms that take graphs where the node locations are already known, and produce paths for the edges?